# variable is undefined, but I have defined as property in class

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have the following code:

**Javascript:**

```
slideShow = {
     ImgsFolder: "images/",
     ImgsSrc: ['img.jpg', 'img2.jpg', 'img3.jpg', 'img4.jpg', 'img5.jpg'],
     MainElem: document.getElementById('SlideShow'),
     ImgElem: (this.MainElem.firstElementChild) ? this.MainElem.firstElementChild : this.MainElem.firstChild
     doit: function(){
          for (i = 0; i < this.ImgsSrc.length; i++) {
               document.writeln(this.ImgsFolder + this.ImgsSrc[i] + "<br/>");
               }
       }

  }
```

When print the value of `ImgElem` variable , gives me error message `this.MainElem is undefined`, and the problem in the last line.
I don' know what's the problem in this part of code

Comment: you could try: `ImgElem: function() { return (this.MainElem.firstElementChild) ? this.MainElem.firstElementChild : this.MainElem.firstChild;}` I'm not 100% this will work as `this` is always a sketchy subject in js

Comment: Set this option after element SlideShow is created (put this after SlideShow elements tag)

Comment: Does the `<elem id="SlideShow">` exist and is this code being run AFTER it's been created?

Comment: `this` doesn't point to the slideShow...

Comment: Have you verified that document.getElementById('SlideShow') is not returning null?

Comment: @mVChr: yes, <div id="SlideShow"> </div> exists.

Comment: It is *impossible* to refer to the object being created via *object literal* notation within the notation itself.

Comment: I refer to the MainElem property in that class, Ok if use 'this' wrong. how can I refer to MainElem property.

Comment: @ Brendan Delumpa : document.getElementById('SlideShow') not return null but return object .

Comment: @LionKing: JavaScript doesn't have classes. The `this` keyword may not work the way you expect.

Comment: @ am not i am: sorry I'm c++ programmer too, and object in js similar to class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment, it is not possible to refer to the object being created via object literal notation from within the notation itself.

You need to fully create the object before you can reference it.

```
slideShow = {
     ImgsFolder: "images/",
     ImgsSrc: ['img.jpg', 'img2.jpg', 'img3.jpg', 'img4.jpg', 'img5.jpg'],
     MainElem: document.getElementById('SlideShow')
}

slideShow.ImgElem = slideshow.MainElem.firstElementChild ||
                    slideshow.MainElem.firstChild
```

---

To refer to the object *during* creation, you need a constructor function.

```
function SlideshowMaker() {
     this.ImgsFolder = "images/",
     this.ImgsSrc = ['img.jpg', 'img2.jpg', 'img3.jpg', 'img4.jpg', 'img5.jpg'],
     this.MainElem = document.getElementById('SlideShow')

     this.ImgElem = this.MainElem.firstElementChild ||
                    this.MainElem.firstChild
}

 // use "new"----v----to create a new object
var slideshow = new SlideshowMaker()
```

Comment: Thanks, Ok but I want to refer to the MainElem property inside the class not outside, how can

Comment: @LionKing: You can't do it while the object is being created *(when using object literal notation)*. It will only work if you use a constructor function to create the object.

Comment: Why this code work : doit: function(){
                    for (i = 0; i < this.ImgsSrc.length; i++) {
                        document.writeln(this.ImgsFolder + this.ImgsSrc[i] + "<br/>");
                    }
                }
                }

Comment: Because `doit` is a method and it is called after the object to which is it bound is created. You can refer to an object as `this` inside its methods.

Comment: @LionKing: If `doit` is called as a method of the `slideshow` object, then `this` *(within the `doit` method)* will be a reference to that object. So `slideshow.doit()` makes `this` refer to `slideshow`.

Comment: Yes, I now understand this can work with method, but property no

Comment: Thanks Mr "am not i am" for Help, and unfortunately for your trouble

Answer (score 1):

In order to use the `this` keyword you have to instantiate object with the `new` keyword. Otherwise the `this` keyword will point to the `window` object in this case.

Comment: You have to add the ImgElem property after the object is created and then reference the object via the variable name slideShow.MainElem

Answer (score 0):

When you use the object literals such as `{ key: value, ... }`, the object is actually created after the whole block is parsed/executed.

```
var a = {
  // a is not defined here
  key: value
};
// it is defined here
```

Also, you cannot use `this` as a reference to the object you are about to create. `this` can only be used in methods of an object (functions bound to the object or executed in their context).

You have two options:

1.) You need to either create a getter function such as

```
var a = {
  b: value,
  c: function () { return this.b.c; }
};
```

and call it in order to access `b.c`: `a.c()`

2.) The better way in your case is to define the property `ImgElem` after the object is actually created:

```
var slideShow = {
 MainElem: document.getElementById('SlideShow')
};
slideShow.ImgElem = slideShow.MainElem.firstElementChild || slideShow.MainElem.firstChild;
```

Notice the usage of `slideShow` instead of `this`.

Comment: Good explain thanks,but now I want to refer to the MainElem property inside the class to use it, Is it possible that and how can

Comment: What is the "class" you are talking about? You have a simple object here. You can access the `MainElem` property as `slideShow.MainElem` (as shown in my code) or as `this.MainElem` in methods of the `slideShow` object (such as `slideShow.method = function(){ … this.MainElem … }`

Comment: That's not the terminology. "class" in JS is a constructor function + its prototype object.

Comment: Thanks Mr "Jan Kuča" for Help, and unfortunately for your trouble

Answer (score -3):

Maybe you have missplaced some parentheses?

```
var slideShow = {
ImgsFolder: "images/",
ImgsSrc: ['img.jpg', 'img2.jpg', 'img3.jpg', 'img4.jpg', 'img5.jpg'],
MainElem: document.getElementById('SlideShow'),
ImgElem: (this.MainElem.firstElementChild ? this.MainElem.firstElementChild :   this.MainElem.firstChild)
}
```